Why does TypeScript not show never type in error when intersecting an object type with a string?
I am trying to understand why TypeScript does not explicitly show a never type in the error messages when intersecting an object type with a string type. Here is my code:
type Test1 = {
    b: number;
    c: string;
} & string;

// Type '{ b: number; c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Test1'.
// Type '{ b: number; c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
let test1: Test1 = {
    b: 1,
    c: 'c',
}

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Test1'.
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ b: number; c: string; }'.
let test1: Test1 = 'test1'

In the above code, Test1 is defined as an intersection of an object type and string. According to my understanding, this should result in a never type because no value can be both an object with properties b and c and a string at the same time.

When trying to assign an object to test1, I get:

Type '{ b: number; c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Test1'.
Type '{ b: number; c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.


When trying to assign a string to test1, I get:

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Test1'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ b: number; c: string; }'.

From my understanding, these should indicate that Test1 is effectively a never type, but TypeScript does not seem to mention never in the error messages. Is this a bug in TypeScript, or is there something I’m missing in how TypeScript handles such intersections?
Any clarification on this behavior would be appreciated. Thank you!

TS supports these to allow for "branded primitives" as described in the FAQ. See the linked q/a above for more information.
